# Rails Mongoid `pluck` equivalent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, mongoid3

In my Rails app I am using MongoID with a Elasticsearch river for text search.

For `@devices_with_config = ConfigTextSearch.search params[:device_id]` 
I want to extract just the `device_id` fields for the matching records in the query. In `mongoID 3.1.0` I could just use `Band.all.pluck(:name)`. But unfortunately, I am stuck with 3.0.23.

I see there is a similar moped expression `collections[:bands].find.select(name: 1)`...but I am new to rails and can't figure out how I would use a moped expression in a controller or model.

Any Ideas on how I can just extract the 'device_id' field in matches with MongoId?

Answer (score 3):

Mongoid has a `pluck` function now.

[mongoid#pluck](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Contextual/Mongo:pluck)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a hold of a Moped collection like this

```
 Band.collection.find.select(name: 1)
```

Comment: Thanks. With `ConfigTextSearch.search("foo").find.select(device_id: 1)` I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) from (pry):46:in `select'`

Comment: `ConfigTextSearch.search("foo")` does not look like a moped collection to me.

Comment: It is using `elasticsearch-rails`, which inherits the methods from MongoId.

Comment: Didn't work with elasticsearch, so you're on your own here, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're not actually building a Mongoid criteria with that call, but I haven't looked into elasticsearch-rails so I can't be 100% sure.

If you're completely unable to update to 3.1.0 you should be able to just monkey patch this functionality in.

```
module Mongoid
  class Criteria
    # select specific fields from collection based on current scope, returned as a hash
    def pluck(*fields)
      raise ArgumentError, 'Call this with at least one field' if fields.empty?

      collection.find(self.selector).select(Hash[fields.map { |field| [field, 1] }]).to_a
    end
  end
end
```

After adding the above code you should be able to do the following:

```
Band.where(name: 'awesome').pluck(:id, :device_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

An equivalent to the pluck method defined in mongoid is:

plucked_array = User.where(:name => 'xyz').map(&: field_to_be_plucked)

Where ***field_to_be_plucked*** is the name of the field whose values need to be plucked out in Array.

Comment: This is loading the whole document (and embedded documents) from mongodb which is pretty inefficient, a better implementation if you're forced to use `map` would be: `User.where(name: 'xyz').only(:email).map(&:email)` which will only load the one field you're looking at :)

Answer (score 0):

Found it....from what I can tell this isn't on the MongoId docs.....

`sue = bob.results.map { |r| r._source.device_id }`

Answer (score 0):

What I used for the same purpose, with Mongoid 3.0 :

```
Band.all.distinct(:name)
```

Warning: relevant only if all the names are different (of if you want to remove duplicates).

Comment: This really does not answer the question.

Comment: I disagree. This solution works (with the limitation I gave as a warning).In my opinion, it seems preferable compared to solution where the rows are iterated in memory (e.g. using map()).